# How to show different snazzy-info-window in marker?

Tags: angular, google-maps

I using [Angular Google Maps(AGM)](https://angular-maps.com/) component. I need to handle two events at the marker - (mouseOver) and (markerClick). In both cases I need to output an informative message, but they will be completely different in content and style.

(mouseOver) should show a simple message, as shown in the [official AGM demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo)

> [mouseOver Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZuzD.jpg)

(markerClick) should show my custom form, like this

> [my custom form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FhJi.jpg)

At the moment I can only display one of these messages, which I describe in the tag <agm-snazzy-info-window>. But I have no idea how I could display both of them (one at a time, depending on the event)